Brave and Google Chrome crashing after Fedora restart
Recently Brave and Google Chrome srated crashing after Fedora restart: any tab or browser manu says : "Oh snap: ERROR" and browser does not work at all. First it started with Google Chrome so I switched to Brave but it also started to crash.
Machine:
Thinkpad 480s with Intel Corei5

Fedora:
NAME="Fedora Linux"
VERSION="40 (Workstation Edition)"
ID=fedora
VERSION_ID=40
VERSION_CODENAME=""
PLATFORM_ID="platform:f40"
PRETTY_NAME="Fedora Linux 40 (Workstation Edition)"

Brave:
Version 1.67.123 Chromium: 126.0.6478.126 (Official Build) unknown (64-bit)

Google Chrome:
Version 126.0.6478.126 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Running sudo dnf update or manually upgrading browsers does not help. Incognito mode also does not work.
Can it be some browser extension issue or Fedora related issue? On Ubuntu it seems to work fine with the same setup.
